# Why my ASP.NET project not loading the Dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, filenotfoundexception

I have an **ASP.NET MVC 4** project. I am referencing a **managed C++ dll** which internally calls methods of an **unmanaged C++ dll**. Problem is that I am getting *"Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies"* error when debugging my project in Visual Studio. The Dll it cannot find is used by the **unmanaged C++ dll**. I am placing all the required DLLs in the bin directory of ASP project.

Everything works fine in a WPF Project but I am getting error when doing the same thing in ASP.NET MVC4 project. Error comes on launching/debugging ASP.NET MVC4 project.

I have tried almost everything I could but not sure why this error is coming.

Ideas?

**Edit**
I tried Fuslogvw.exe and it is creating two output/log file. I am a bit confused from its output

at one file it says at the end

> Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9abdb93b\4655bb86\assembly\dl3\5113eba9\008d3984_ccb1cb01\Assembly.dll.
>   LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context."

In second log it says

> === Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: DisplayName = AssemblyName  (Partial)
>   WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an
>   assembly:
>   WRN: Assembly Name: AssemblyName | Domain ID: 2
>   WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is
>   provided.
>   WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
>   WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified
>   textual identity for the assembly,
>   WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
>   WRN: See whitepaper > http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue.
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/users/haris.hasan/documents/visual studio
>   2012/Projects/MvcApplication1/MvcApplication1/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = c:\users\haris.hasan\documents\visual studio
>   2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\bin
>   LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9abdb93b 
>   LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9abdb93b 
>   LOG: AppName = 4655bb86 Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === WRN: No matching native image found.
>   LOG: IL assembly loaded from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9abdb93b\4655bb86\assembly\dl3\5113eba9\008d3984_ccb1cb01\AssemblyName.dll.

Comment: Maybe some dependency from the WPF proyect is not in your MVC 4 proyect. Pay atention to `or one of its dependencies`. I mean, compare your references from both proyects.

Comment: @lante both have same references

Comment: Try Fuslogvw.exe it should tell you what is and isn't being loaded; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

Comment: @DaveAnderson I tried that and I am confused with it's output. I am updating my question with fuslogvw related findings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- It can be because of MS C++ redistributable package updates! Uninstall them and reinstall again. 
 2- I think IIS is creating a shadow copy of each managed dll in a path but for unmanaged another path You have to configure that. Chek that [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2007/08/31/loading-c-assemblies-in-asp-net.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on a x64 platform? Then it is possible that IIS is running in x64 mode and simply doesn't load x86 dll's.

You can test this out by setting the relevant IIS Application Pool to x86 mode (enable32BitAppOnWin64 => true) and test if that is working correctly.

Additionally, it's possible that the security settings of the managed DLL and / or C++ dll prevent it from loading. On the C++ dll, make sure at the very least the group "authenticated users" can read it.

Comment: IISExpress process is 32 bit so I think `enable32BitAppOnWin64` won't do anything.